# Find the matrix of f with respect to basis $\{(2,1),(-1,2)\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f(x,y)=x_1y_1+x_2y_2,~x=(x_1,x_2),~y=(y_1,y_2)$. Find the matrix of f with respect to basis $\{(2,1),(-1,2)\}$.

My attempt:

Normally I should find the matrix with respect to standard basis. Then I should use this theorem $T'=B^{-1}TB$

But I couldnt even write anything.

Comment: Do you know how we define the matrix of a bilinear form?

Comment: $[f]_B = A$ s.t. $A_{ij} = f(b_i, b_j)$

Comment: All right.  And what matrix results from using that property here with the bilinear form $f$ and the given ordered basis?